# C# Basic Syntax Error - No Idea What I've Done Wrong, But Probably Quite Simple

Tags: c#, syntax, syntax-error

couldn't think of a better title. I just want someone to let me know what is wrong with this code:

```
public AddressChooser(string argstreet, string argsuburb, string argcountry, string argstate, string argunit, int argstreetNumber, int argpostCode)
        {
            streetNameBox.Text = argstreet;
            suburbBox.Text = argsuburb;
            countryBox.Text = argcountry;
            stateBox.Text = argstate;
            unitBox.Text = argunit;
            streetNumberBox.Value = argstreetNumber;
            postCodeBox.Value = argpostCode;
            InitializeComponent();
            cancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            save.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
```

The error returned is:

```
  System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=MultipleForms
  StackTrace:
       at MultipleForms.AddressChooser..ctor(String argstreet, String argsuburb, String argcountry, String argstate, String argunit, Int32 argstreetNumber, Int32 argpostCode) in C:\Users\Yoshie\Local Settings\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MultipleForms\MultipleForms\Address Selector.cs:line 17
       at MultipleForms.Form1.changeAddress_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Yoshie\Local Settings\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MultipleForms\MultipleForms\MultiForm Example.cs:line 23
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at MultipleForms.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Yoshie\Local Settings\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MultipleForms\MultipleForms\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: It's been ages since I've worked on WinForms, but don't you need to call InitializeComponent() before trying to set values on the text boxes? If I remember correctly, that's where the controls get constructed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a syntax error, otherwise it would have been a *compile-time* failure.

This is likely to be the problem:

```
streetNameBox.Text = argstreet;
```

You've set that *before* calling `InitializeComponent()`, so `streetNameBox` will still be null.

You should probably call `InitializeComponent` so that all the designer-related fields can be initialized before you perform the rest of your construction.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 3):

You have initialize component after assigning to some controls - I suspect they are null

Initialize Component must come first before you try to use any controls

Answer (score 2):

InitializeComponent needs to be the first line.

This is because it creates all of your Windows Forms components. You're trying to access one of the components before it's created, giving a NullReferenceException.

Comment: *REMOVED* - I was saying how you answered first, but then I saw that you hadn't

Comment: P.S. I can't believe I didn't see that!